# A prime problem in Fibonacci sequence

Tags: number-theory, fibonacci-numbers, prime-factorization

This problem can be a little too wild but have at it anyways:

> Prove that for every positive integer $n$ $\geqslant$ $7$ , $f_{n+1}$ has a prime divisor that doesn't divide $f_{n}-1$ where $f_{n}$ is the n-th number in the fibbonachi sequence.

Comment: Interesting problem.  Please provide some additional context as to where you came across it and what your own thoughts have been toward solving it.

Comment: Is it true?  $F_{12}=144$ and $F_{11}=89$ so...

Comment: Actually I'm new to college math and its my first time I'm studying analytic number theory so I have no hope of solving this but my instructor actually gave this to me as an interesting problem to think on whenever I had time and so far, I've made nothing out of it

Comment: Oh Im sorry it was minus

Comment: Changed it
Sorry

Comment: @AryanHemmati I don't think that helps.

Comment: @lulu, good catch. I wonder if there are any further counterexamples to the OP's mistaken plus-sign assertion, or if they have inadvertently come up with something new (for $n\ge13$ instead of $7$).

Comment: $F_{12} =144$ is not a counterexample, is it? $3 | 144$ but $3 \not | 88,$ right?

Comment: @stuartstevenson, what do you mean? I don't see any obvious counterexample with the minus sign

Comment: @AsemAbdelraouf, $144$ was a counterexample when it was $f(n)+1$ instead of $f(n)-1$.

Comment: Can you try proof by contradiction?

Comment: Do you have an idea to prove with contradiction? Because I'm really stuck

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Starting from Cassini's identity:

$$F_{n+1}F_{n-1}-F_{n}^2=(-1)^n$$

and adding $1$ to both sides we get:

$$F_{n+1}F_{n-1}-(F_{n}+1)(F_{n}-1)=(-1)^n+1$$

When $n$ is even, the RHS is $2$. Since the only fibonacci numbers which are a power of $2$ are $F_3=2$ and $F_6 = 8$ (see e.g. [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/795763/573047)), then $F_{n+1}$ ($n+1 \gt 6$ for $n \ge 7$) has one or more odd prime factors, but none of them can divide $F_n-1$, otherwise it would divide $2$.

When $n$ is odd, the RHS is $0$. $F_n+1$ and $F_n-1$ cannot have any common factor other than $2$. $F_{n+1}$ and $F_{n-1}$ are coprime. Then, if all prime factors of $F_{n+1}$ divide $F_{n}-1$ we have:

$$F_{n+1}=2^{k}(F_n-1)$$

for some $k \gt 0$. If $k = 1$ we have $F_{n+1}=F_n+F_{n-1}=2F_n-2$ and then $F_{n-1}=F_n-2$, impossible, otherwise still an absurd:

$$F_n = \frac{F_{n-1}+2^k}{2^k-1} \lt F_{n-1}$$

because:

$$F_{n-1} \gt \frac{2^k}{2^k-2}$$

Comment: Wow... Seriously didn't think of it to write an identity and work on it :) thanks